# Defining equation with variable in the exponent

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to define and plot the following equation.

f(x,y) = Sin(x^4) – Cos(12x^y) + 0.7x

is this the correct way to do it?

f[x_, y_] := Sin[x^4] - Cos[12 x^y] + 0.7 x

Would this be a correct representation of the equation?
I'm trying to find out if any value of y will make f(x,y) positive, even when x is negative.

[image]

Comment: Your translation of the maths into Mathematica looks correct.  But your question is very basic so I'm moved to ask how you have not managed to confirm this for yourself ?  The way to learn Mathematica is not to seek help from a guru at every step on the way, but to experiment, even read the documentation.

Comment: Also, your problem is mathematically easy to answer, without using Mathematica. Just replace `x` with a nice integer less than `-2` (for example `-10` and convince yourself that you can't find a value of `y`that makes `f > 0`

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Sorry for the noobish question. I was working on this at about 3am. I tried seeing if this was correct by using wolfram, but wolfram refused to plot it out. I managed to get all of my other plots working before I came to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is correct. You might want to do a 3D plot:

```
f[x_, y_] := Sin[x^4] - Cos[12 x^y] + 0.7 x
Plot3D[f[x,y],{x,-2,2},{y,-2,2}]
```

This will plot `f` for `-2<x<2` and `-2<y<2`. Good luck!